# Can someone help me with onclick events created programmatically?

Tags: onclick, dojo

I have a script that generates a set of divs programmatically, but I can't figure out how to get the onclick events to work for each div independently.

[sample code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Q4P.gif)

```
for (i = 0;i < allEntries.length;i++) {
    //Build a div for this entry
    var containerID = "dayTimeMinutesContainer-" + allEntries[i][10] + "-" + allEntries[i][6];
    var contSubj = allEntries[i][4];
    var divid = allEntries[i][12];

    dojo.query(dojo.create("div",{id:divid},containerID))
        .onclick(function(){alert(contSubj);  //returns the last subject for all entries  ???
        });
}
```

As shown in the code snippet, the onclick event fires for each div created - but it ALWAYS returns the Subject (contSubj) from the last entry processed in the loop, regardless of the entry clicked.

I'm a dojo rookie, so I apologize if this seems to be a simple oversight.  I've spent hours seeking a solution, but haven't found anything similar.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  How can I create onclick events to work for each individual divid processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION... Thank you for the responses... always good to get additional insight.  I used the callback suggestion and solved this dilemma as shown.

```
for (i = 0;i < allEntries.length;i++) {
    //Build a div for this entry
    var containerID = "dayTimeMinutesContainer-" + allEntries[i][10] + "-" + allEntries[i][6];
    var contSubj = allEntries[i][4];
    var divid = allEntries[i][12];

    dojo.query(dojo.create("div",{id:divid},containerID))
        .onclick(createCallback(contSubj));  
}

function createCallback( subj ){
  return function(){
      alert(subj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code directly in the post and not as image.

The issue is not with the event. It the variable `contSubj` which is the culprit. In JavaScript a variable is function scoped. You have defined the `contSubj` outside the function scope of click callback function. So it will always have the value of the last item of for loop.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the contSubj var should be defined within the onclick function?  Can you give me the correct syntax for that?

Comment: Adding to this, you can set `contSubj` as DOM property and when `onclick` is fired get the property from `event.target` and return it. This would ensure that appropriate `contSubj` is returned for every node.